# writing huge amount of string to a file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to run this code in java. However, when I open my file, it is completely empty. I dont understand why and need help.
For some image processing purposes I try to exctract every single pixel with their RGB values. Why is my file empty?

```
        class Pixel {
           BufferedImage image;
           int width;
           int height;

           public Pixel() {
              try {
                 File input = new File("originalLeopard.jpg");
                 image = ImageIO.read(input);
                 width = image.getWidth();
                 height = image.getHeight();
                 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("pixy.txt"));

                 for(int y=0; y < height; y++){

                    for(int x=0; x <width; x++){

                       Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(y, x));
                       writer.write(y + " " + x +" "+ c.getRed()+ " " + c.getGreen()+ " "+ c.getBlue()+"\n");

                    }
                 }
                 writer.close();
              }

              catch (Exception e) {

              }

           }

           static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
           {
              Pixel obj = new Pixel();
           }
        }
```

Comment: What is `BufferedWriter`? Does it even work?

Comment: Is the file written to a different folder?

Comment: no file is in the src folder or workplace folder

Comment: By the way, program runs without an error

Comment: Exceptions are being ignored.

Comment: does it matter?

Comment: I mean there is no exceptional case

Comment: @OnurTR How do you know, when you just throw the exception away?

Comment: This is the equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears and saying "I can't hear you!" There's no way of knowing if there are exceptions because you ignore them.

Comment: I think I am wrong :( you are right. should I call e.getStackTrace();

Comment: I dont remember the method to call for exceptions

Comment: You should not catch the exception at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is because you wrote `image.getRGB(y,x)` instead of `image.getRGB(x,y)`

Comment: Thanks a loooooottttt

Answer (score 5):

you are catching all Exceptions but not printing out the stacktrace. this would have shown you your code is throwing :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)
at com.unionsystemsltd.optimus.secure.jwt.Pixel.<init>(Pixel.java:35)
at com.unionsystemsltd.optimus.secure.jwt.Pixel.main(Pixel.java:51)
```

Comment: And it's caused by `image.getRGB(y, x)`, since method is declared as [`getRGB(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-).